# Applescript to click on a specific application in the Mac Status Bar

Tags: macos, testing, automation, applescript, automated-tests

I have an OS X application that runs as a status bar app. I am trying to do a test automation. Is there a way to click the status bar app using Apple Script?

The script given below works only on native apps.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer" to click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
```

I am looking for a similar functionality on custom apps.

Comment: What do you mean as a status bar app? Is it a window with a progress indicator? Do you mean as a menu icon only? If so, you can not access it via applescript unless the app has a dictionary.

Comment: By status bar app, I meant apps like Google Drive. Like the apps given in this link - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/pimp-macs-menu-bar-best-tweaks-apps/

Comment: Ok, FYI, those are called "Menu Bar Extras". You can not reliably script access to them. The order can change. Some can be hidden in some contexts.

Comment: If you want to find a solution (if there is one), please give a specific example (like which of those apps you're most interested in working with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all Menu Bar Extras (or status icons) can be accessed through UI Scripting. You have to experiment with whether they can be called through a unique description or other value.
Play with code like this to see if you can figure it out:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 where description is "clock")
        click
        click menu item "Open Date & Time Preferences…" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

If you can't find it there, you can try menu bar 2 for Status items.

Comment: If I am developing an application, is there anything that I need to do to enable UI Scripting? I am trying to do an automated testing on my apps.

Comment: Yes, make sure your Menu Bar Extra is placed in menu bar 1, and that you fill in the content for things like role description, title, name, and description.

Comment: And, include a sample script with your app distro. That is the MOST helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I have to go through https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001982-BCICHGIE